# Drupal 7 multisite not working

Tags: apache, drupal, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a multisite for an existing drupal 7 site.
What I've done is

1. Created a db and imported the existing sites db to use with the new site
2. Created a folder inside sites directory called mysite.local and copied settings.ph and changed the db configurations with the new one.
3. Added an entry in /etc/hosts file.

   *127.0.0.1   mysite.local*
4. Added a file mysite.local.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available and added the following lines.

   ```
       
           DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/drupal/sites/mysite.local"
           ServerName mysite.local
           ServerAlias mysite.local
       `
   ```

   and enabled the site.
5. Then added a symbolic link to this directory

   ln -s /var/www/html/drupal /var/www/html/drupal/sites/mysite.local

But I am getting 403 while accessig mysite.local.

Can any one help me to figure out what is going wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is a multisite you need to point it to the root directory. Drupal will figure out based off the domain name where to pull the settings.php from. Change your DocumentRoot back to /var/www/html/drupal